# How to get to Easter Island?

Tags: transportation, chile, easter-island

Once in my life I would really like to see those statues from the Easter Island.

[image]
Image from Wikipedia.

Since it is really far away from anywhere else, I wonder how I can get there. Is there an airport on the island that I can use as a tourist? And can I fly in from Chile? Or are there any other direct flights (also from other countries)? Is it also possible to go there by ship?

And how many time should I allow myself to spend there? Can I see the stuff in 1 day, 1 week, 1 month?

Comment: Most of the things still apply (except for the prices): http://www.guardian.co.uk/travel/2003/sep/20/userstraveladvice

Comment: I'll add another question: is it possible to get there from other country? (not Chile)

Comment: @Ivan I thought I included it with other direct flights, but now I made it more clear. Thanks.

Comment: I'd been told the cheapest way to get there is to include it as a stop on a [round-the-world](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/around-the-world) plane ticket, but maybe costs have gone down since then or maybe I'm confusing it with the Galapagos.

Comment: British author Douglas Adams claimed he ended up on Easter Island by accident (plane refueling) while flying from South America to Australia.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Lonely Planet has information on this](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/chile/rapa-nui-easter-island/transport/getting-there-away). There are flights from/to Santiago and from/to Papeete. Some people choose this connection just to travel between France and Tahiti by avoiding annoyances of a transit through the USA.

> Lan Airlines (100-920; Av Atamu Tekena s/n; 9am-4:30pm Mon-Fri &
>   9am-12:30pm Sat), near Av Pont, is the only airline serving Rapa Nui.
>   It has four flights per week to/from Santiago and two per week to/from
>   Papeete (Tahiti). A standard economy round-trip fare from Santiago can
>   range from US$700 to US$900. Flights are often overbooked, so it is
>   essential to reconfirm your ticket two days before departure.

Comment: [According to Wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Easter_Island#Get_in), besides Santiago de Chile, there are also flights from Lima, Peru.

Comment: Flights from Lima are seasonal.

Comment: Flights from Lima have been suspended according to http://imaginaisladepascua.com/como-llegar-a-isla-de-pascua/