# Are there any other airlines besides LATAM going to Easter Island from Chile?

Tags: air-travel, airlines, chile, easter-island

I want to go to Easter Island but on the date I choose for travelling all seats on the LATAM flight to the island are already booked. Is there any other airline leaving from Chile (any city) to Easter Island? If not, other airlines from any other country?

Comment: You can get there from Tahiti, but only once a week. Other than that, nope, that is all there is.

Comment: Wikipedia claims there is a seasonal service from Peru https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mataveri_International_Airport you could check.

Comment: @KateGregory: I googled and found that the flights from Lima were suspended: http://imaginaisladepascua.com/como-llegar-a-isla-de-pascua/ "Hace unos pocos años Lan abrió una nueva ruta con vuelo directo desde Lima (Perú) pero después de unos meses operando, paró su funcionamiento y por el momento no se sabe si volverán a abrirla."

Comment: @KateGregory: Why don't you transform your comment into an answer and I could accept it (after a day or two)?

Comment: For non-Spanish speakers: according to my rusty Spanish, the quote in Stockfisch's comment says in English: "A few years ago, LAN started a new route with a direct flight from Lima (Peru), but after a few months in operation, service was stopped, and for the moment, nobody knows if it will restart."

Comment: @KateGregory is correct: Only LATAM flies to Easter Island. Only from Santiago (from where you sometimes can get decent fares) and from Tahiti (which tends to be very expensive).

Comment: [How to get to Easter Island?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4250/13777)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was in the airport on Easter Island in August of 2015. The only airline counter there is LAN (LATAM). No other airlines have any facilities. LAN offers daily flights from Santiago and weekly (some web sites say twice a week) from Tahiti. These are your only options.

The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mataveri_International_Airport) page for the airport says there is seasonal service (also by LAN) from Lima Peru but this has apparently been [suspended](http://imaginaisladepascua.com/como-llegar-a-isla-de-pascua/).